# Moved Facebook app to a new server, now its broken

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

My app was working fine on my server. I moved it to another server, updated all the app settings in developers.facebook.com and now all i get is a blank page. The error_log for the server shows this error.

[Wed May 23 22:20:01 2012] [error] [client 184.65.142.249] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://static.ak.facebook.com/platform/page_proxy.php?v=4
[Wed May 23 22:20:01 2012] [error] [client 184.65.142.249] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/explorebc/home.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://static.ak.facebook.com/platform/page_proxy.php?v=4

I've searched high and low for an answer to this, I could really use somebody's help for a push in the right direction.

The paths are right, the facebook settings are right, the init call is in there, the config file has been updated with new server paths.

Cheers,

Cody

Comment: Set permissions? (chmod)

Comment: http://webomania.wordpress.com/2007/03/12/permission-denied-in-unknown-on-line-0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was SELinux that was blocking the site from working correctly. It was unrelated to code or direction, it was just simply blocking things from working.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the right permissions are set for files. [[Source]](http://www.000webhost.com/forum/customer-assistance/19975-fatal-error-unknown-failed-opening-required-www-cjenovnik-comoj-com-index-php-i.html)

Comment: Thats not really an answer, more of a suggestion. Can you specifically recommend how to set those perm's? I have chmod'd 777 the entire directory and parent directory and chown'd apache:apache everything. I don't believe it to be a perm's issue, but maybe you can recommend something further?